# Javascript extract subject property(ies) and value(s) from predicate to form object

Tags: typescript, properties, predicate, extract, arrow-functions

Given a function `findOneOrFail`;

```js
/**
 * Finds first entity that matches given options.
 */
findOneOrFail(options?: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity>;
```

Used like;

```js
const email = "bob@bob.com";
const user: User = await this.userRepo.findOneOrFail({ email: email });
```

This will return first result that matches the condition that the email equals "bob@bob.com".

I am attempting to extend `findOneOrFail` by creating a new function `getUserBy` which I can use like this;

```js
const email = "bob@bob.com";
const user: User = await this.userRepo.getUserBy(u => u.email === email);
```

Is this possible? I need to extract the property and value from the predicate.

```js
public async getUserBy(predicate: (u: User) => void): Promise<User> {
    let user: User;
    try {
        const condition = {}; // Some how use the predicate to 
        // extract the condition { propety: "value" }
        user = await this._userOrm.findOneOrFail(condition);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof EntityNotFoundError) {
            return null;
        }
        throw error;
    }
    return user;
}
```

Please note the `FindOneOptions<T>` interface is defined [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/find-options/FindOneOptions.ts)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something more complex than checking equality of columns (or other search functionality provided by your underlying database), you could get all the rows from the table and perform an array search, keeping in mind the fact that this query will not be optimized by your database.

Comment: Yes, I see how what I want to have can do much more than just equality. Which is all the orm can support with that function. So I will abandon this approach.